# Keepass: Synchronize with URL via FTP problem

Tags: windows, ftp, keepass

How described in [this page](http://keepass.info/help/v2/ioconnect.html) of the KeePass Help Center I can sync my database via ftp. But an error has been occurred:

> The server returned an address in response to the PASV command that is different than the address to which the FTP connection was made

This occurs in the passive mode: Keepass switch in this mode because the firewall on my PC does not allow incoming connections.

If I use the Total Commander all is okey:

> Connect to: (20.04.2011 23:01:21)
>
> hostname=50.19.yyy.zz
>
> username=foo
>
> startdir=
>
> 220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
>
> USER foo
>
> 331 Please specify the password.
>
> PASS ***********
>
> 230 Login successful.
>
> SYST
>
> 215 UNIX Type: L8
>
> FEAT
>
> 211-Features:
>
> EPRT
>
> EPSV
>
> MDTM
>
> PASV
>
> REST STREAM
>
> SIZE
>
> TVFS
>
> UTF8
>
> 211 End
>
> OPTS UTF8 ON
>
> 200 Always in UTF8 mode.
>
> Connect ok!
>
> PWD
>
> 257 "/home/foo"
>
> Get directory
>
> TYPE A
>
> 200 Switching to ASCII mode.
>
> PASV
>
> 227 Entering Passive Mode (10,208,121,27,224,188).
>
> Server reports local IP -> Redirect to: 50.19.yyy.zz
>
> LIST
>
> 150 Here comes the directory listing.
>
> Download
>
> Waiting for server...
>
> 226 Directory send OK.

It is because in this `Server reports local IP -> Redirect to: 50.19.yyy.zz` Total Commander do that Keepass does not do. FTP server return its local network address in response instead of public and Keepass falls down. What to do to solve the problem? FTP server is my server in Amazon EC2.

Comment: The answer to this is to configure your FTP server to always report the external IP address, which is usually done by hard-coding that in to the config somewhere. Where "somewhere" is, and how it's done, is dependent upon what software you're using. Without that information, we're not going to be able to offer much help here.

Comment: I'm using free instance [ami-8e1fece7](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/) and [vsftpd](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/) FTP server.
`Name        : vsftpd                       Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2.2.2                             Vendor: Amazon.com
Release     : 6.5.amzn1                     Build Date: Wed 23 Mar 2011 12:59:30 AM UTC
Install Date: Wed 20 Apr 2011 10:40:27 AM UTC      Build Host: build-31003.build
Group       : System Environment/Daemons    Source RPM: vsftpd-2.2.2-6.5.amzn1.src.rpm
`

Comment: I got the [answer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/forums/forum/329221/topic/4497695) from KeePass Password Safe help forum. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved by adding `pasv_address=50.19.yyy.zz` in `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` - the config file of my FTP server. Thanks. It was problem of the FTP server.